# Firefox add-on is shown beside search box on desktop, but where is it on Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

I installed [Search by Image](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/search_by_image) Firefox add-on. But I can't see the extension button that we see next to search box on desktop version.

Where do I find it?

Comment: In case someone is looking for developing add-ons for firefox on Android see this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137578/199004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox add-ons for Android by default do not appear next to the search box, unless the add-on has an option to show it there.

You need to tap the 3 dot (**`⋮`**) menu to reveal them. They could be separately listed as with this example or shown under the add-ons (blue circle with arrow)

. 
[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)